# Laravel parse date and get difference in minutes

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am trying to get the minutes difference it always return a positive integer is there a way in which we can get the integer value. here is the code that i have tried so for

```
      $connections = ChatConnection::all();

    foreach ($connections as $con) {
        $monthdate = Carbon::parse($con->last_connected_at)->addMinute(5);
        $dateDiff = Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($monthdate);

        $this->info($dateDiff);

    }
```

`$this->info($dateDiff);` this return a positive integer always.

I have to check the column send push notification if message connection is 5 minutes old.

Is there a nice way?

Answer (score 7):

In default, `diffInMinutes()` always returns positive integer.

In order to get both positive negative values of difference,

You have add `false` parameter in `diffInMinutes()` function like this:

```
foreach ($connections as $con) {
    $monthdate = Carbon::parse($con->last_connected_at)->addMinute(5);
    $dateDiff = Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($monthdate,false);

    $this->info($dateDiff);
}
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Add `last_connected_at` to the $dates in your model:
`protected $dates = ['last_connected_at'];`
Then laravel always gives back a carbon instance.

Than you can do the following

```
$connections = ChatConnection::all();

foreach ($connections as $con) {
    if($con->last_connected_at > Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)){
        // Code
    }
}
```

Or refactor to this

```
$connections = ChatConnection::all();

$connections->each(function($con){
    if($con->last_connected_at > Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)){
        // Code
    }
});
```